# Hide range input if not compatible

Tags: javascript, css, html

I use a range input to adjust zoom in my web application. I use some JavaScript to synchronize it with a text input next to it so users can see the value as they move the slider, and they can also type the value they want.

```html
<input type="range" name="amountRange" min="0" max="20" value="0" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value" />
<input type="number" name="amountInput" min="0" max="20" value="0" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value" />
```

The problem is that some browsers (mainly IE9 which I want to support) are not compatible with range inputs, so the range will be displayed as a textbox. That means they will see two text-boxes like that:

```html
<input type="text" name="amountRange" min="0" max="20" value="0" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value" />
<input type="text" name="amountInput" min="0" max="20" value="0" onchange="this.previousElementSibling.value=this.value" />
```

How should I hide the range input if the browser isn't compatible with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can feature-detect input type like so:

```
var rangeInput = document.forms.myformname.amountRange;
if (rangeInput.type === 'range') {
  // This browser supports range.
}
else {
  rangeInput.style.display 'none';
}
```

It seems that trying to set `input.type = "somethingIEdoesntunderstand"` will actually result in an error in IE9; and all browsers will filter the possible types to what they know.

Comment: Oh, so `input.type` defaults to "text" on older browsers? Well, that was simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily handle all html browser incompatibility and use them in your advantage with **[modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/)** , make sure to import the library :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

and then inspect your web page in IE , within the HTML tag you'll find some attribute starting with the word "no" something like no-canvas and so on, all unsupported features will start with no-HTML-or-CSS , and you can use this to apply whatever style you want .

exemple :

```
.no-cssreflections {
            border-radius: 15px;
        }
```

Comment: It's an interesting library, but I don't think I'll use it for this site, which only needs to be compatible with IE9 and later. Thanks for sharing nonetheless.